# c++, Undefined reference to.functions declared in namespace. Why?

Tags: c++, reference, namespaces

I have declared files structure as below. Compiler says **undefined reference to `SystemStorage::initialize(int, int, int)**. I truly have no idea why :?

systemStorage.h

```
#ifndef SYSTEM_STORAGE_H
#define SYSTEM_STORAGE_H

namespace SystemStorage {
  void initialize(int light_sensor, int led, int sampling);
}

#endif
```

systemStorage.cpp

```
#include "systemStorage.h"

namespace SystemStorage{
  void initialize(int light_sensor, int led, int sampling){
     //instructions to do ...
  }
}
```

Main file:

```
#include "functions/systemStorage.h"

void setup() {
  SystemStorage::initialize(1, 2, 3);   
}
```

Comment: "Compiler says undefined reference" - Nope. That's the *linker* complaining.

Comment: Maybe the object file for `systemStorage.cpp` was not compiled into the executable.

Comment: I'm guessing you didn't supply the .cpp to your compilation command. Please edit your post and supply what you used.

Comment: Yea, you are right, these guys are not compiled

Comment: "I'm guessing you didn't supply the .cpp to your compilation command. "

Comment: Working now, thx